# How can I pass input to output in bash?

Tags: bash, redirect

I am trying to streamline a README, where I can easily pass commands and their outputs to a document. This step seems harder than I thought it would be.

I am trying to pass the input and output to a file, but everything I am trying just either displays `echo test` or `test`

The latest iteration, which is becoming absurd is:

`echo test | xargs echo '#' | cat <(echo) <(cat -)` just shows `# test`

I would like the results to be:

`echo test`

`# test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a bash function to demonstrate a command and its output like this:

```
democommand() {
    printf '#'
    printf ' %q' "$@"
    printf '\n'
    "$@"
}
```

This prints "#", then each argument the function was passed (i.e. the command and its arguments) with a space before each one (and the `%q` makes it quote/escape them as needed), then a newline, and then finally it runs all of its arguments as a command. Here's an example:

```
$ democommand echo test
# echo test
$ democommand ls
# ls
Desktop     Downloads   Movies      Pictures    Sites
Documents   Library     Music       Public
```

Now, as for why your command didn't work... well, I'm not clear what you thought it was doing, but here's what it's actually doing:

- The first command in the pipeline, `echo test`, simply prints the string "test" to its standard output, which is piped to the next command in the chain.
- 'xargs echo '#'`takes its input ("test") and adds it to the command it's given (`echo '#'`) as additional arguments. Essentially, it executes the command`echo '#' test`. This outputs "# test" to the next command in the chain.
- `cat <(echo) <(cat -)` is rather complicated, so let's break it down:

  - `echo` prints a blank line
  - `cat -` simply copies its input (which is at this point in the pipeline is still coming from the output of the `xargs` command, i.e. "# test").
  - `cat <(echo) <(cat -)` takes the output of those two `<()` commands and concatenates them together, resulting in a blank line followed by "# test".

Comment: Thank you very much. Very creative thinking! I never really understood the left redirects, and your explanation has cleared it up a little

Answer (score 1):

Pass the command as a literal string so that you can both print and evaluate it:

```
doc() { printf '$ %s\n%s\n' "$1" "$(eval "$1")"; }
```

Running:

```
doc 'echo foo | tr f c' > myfile
```

Will make `myfile` contain:

```
$ echo foo | tr f c
coo
```